# Find the median in an unsorted read-only array

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, median, space-complexity

Given a read-only array with `n` elements, find the median (the `ceiling(n/2)`-th element by size) in the array, with `O(logn)` space and average time `O(nlogn)`.

- The elements in the array are different.
- The array is not sorted.
- You can't change any of the values in the array, only read them

I thought about using the idea of Quicksort but it is impossible to perform it without changing the array. And to copy to another array would exceed the required space.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant, but  I'll have to insert all the elements into two heaps which will take O(n) space

Comment: Voting to reopen. ` As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking` problem statement is very clear. The OP showed his two approaches, and explained why they fail (demonstrating self research). Will be happy if one of the close voters can explain their reasoining.

Comment: @amit I was about to ask the same question, I want an algorithm that find the median without changing in the given array, I wonder why they closed this question!!

Answer (score 6):

You can solve it using divide and conquer approach, find a random element in between the minimum and maximum, check if it's median, if the median is lower or higher than it, and reduce the problem to a smaller size only on a subrange of the array.

1. Set `min` as the smallest element in the array, and `max` as the biggest one.
2. Choose a random number `mid` in range (`min < mid < max`), if there is no such `mid`, either `min` or `max` is median, find which and you are done.
3. Check if either of `min`, `mid` or `max` is the median (linear search, count how many are bigger/smaller).

   3.1. If so,you are done.

   3.2. Otherwise, the median is in between `(min,mid)` or `(mid,max)`, and you know where (if more are higher than mid or lower than it).

   3.3. If it's in `(min,mid)`, set `max = mid`, otherwise, set `min = mid`.

   3.4. Return to 2.

---

Correctness:

- If the algorithm finds a number - the stop clause is only due to finding the median.
- For each iteration, the median is still in `(min,max)` (formal proof with induction..), and the range is guaranteed to shrink in each iteration, so the algorithm is guaranteed to stop and yield some result.

---

Time complexity:

- Step 1: repeats only once and takes `O(n)` time.
- Step 2: takes `O(n)` time (finding the distinct numbers in range) and repeats each iteration.
- Step 3: takes `O(n)` time (going through each range is linear).

There are `O(logn)` iterations on average case (similar to binary search reasoning).

This gives us `O(nlogn)` time complexity

---

Space complexity:

Implementation dependent, but with tail recursion (similar to the above high level pseudo code) can actually be `O(1)`. With regular recursion this is `O(logn)`, for the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Could you  explain again why another O (logn) is needed in memory for the stack.

Comment: @Robert This solution requires `O(1)` extra memory, but if you instead move it to recursive call, and do not optimize it to tail recursion, there are `O(logn)` recursive calls, each pushes some variables to the calls stack, which gives you `O(logn)` space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algorithm. It consists of searching for the median by keeping track of the lower and upper bound of an interval where the median is.

Let E be the list of elements. Set the lower and upper bounds, L and U, of the median to null.

For every element e in E,

1. If L is not null and e < L, e cannot be the median, skip to next element. If U is not null and e > U, e cannot be the median, skip to next element.
2. Scan E and count the number B of elements before e, and the number A of elements after e.
3. If A = B, e is the median, terminate. If A = B + 1, there is no single median, but e is immediately before the median point, terminate. If B = A + 1, there is no single median, but e is immediately after the median point, terminate.
4. If A > B, the median is after e, set L = e. If B > A, the median is before e, set U = e.

Space complexity is O(1). Time complexity is at most O(n<sup>2</sup>) and O(nlogn) on average.

Example:

```
E = [2 4 7 9 0 6 5]
       L,U = null,null  Initial state.
e = 2  L,U = 2,null     Update L.
e = 4  L,U = 4,null     Update L.
e = 7  L,U = 4,7        Update U.
e = 9  L,U = 4,7        Skip 9.
e = 0  L,U = 4,7        Skip 0.
e = 6  L,U = 4,6        Update U.
e = 5  Median is 5      Terminate.
```

Comment: This seems like a harder-to-read version of amit's proposed algorithm, posted over 20 minutes later.

Comment: @tucuxi  Well, maybe, but it is much more detailed. amit's gives only high-levels steps. The algorithm I suggest is probably easier to implement.